# Grafico não altera mesmo passando dados

Tags: javascript, front-end

Estou puxando dados do BD mas não esta aparecendo no gráfico nos campos de data correto, alguém pode dar uma olhada no meu código ver onde estou errando... vou deixar algumas imagens

---------------- explicação ----------------

O grafico é criado por 3 coisas que vem do select:
Data, que é sempre o dia anterior sysdate -1…
Ativo: que é por exemplo (MOTO,CARRO,CAMINHÃO) que foi usado nessa Data
QTDE_HORAS: que é a quantidade de horas que cada ativo ficou em “uso”. na Data também…

---------------- explicação ----------------

[image: Data funcionando corretamente, Ativos pegando todos corretamente, Horas também... mas não está carregando nos dias certos as informações, compare na próxima imagem]

[image: Select que está sendo feito e como era para estar no grafico]

Ele está mostrando no grafico, ele puxa a data e coloca em baixo do gráfico conforme a imagem, também separa os ativos por cores, só não está Inserindo essas informações no gráfico corretamente…

Alguém pode dar uma revisada já tentei diversas formas, acho que estou deixando passar algo sem perceber

Script:

```
var aLabels =[];    
    var qtdDatas=0;
    var dados = [];
    var ativos =[];
    var qtdAtivos=6;
    var cont=6;

    var data = [];
    var ativo = [];
    var aproveitamento = [];

    var valordados =[];

    <struts_logic:iterate id="arrExecute" name="collExecuteList1" scope="page" type="java.util.ArrayList">

        //Vetor de labels (informação abaixo das barras)
        if( !aLabels.includes("<%=arrExecute.get(0).toString()%>") ){    
            qtdDatas = aLabels.push("<%=arrExecute.get(0).toString()%>");
        }
        if( !ativos.includes("<%=arrExecute.get(1).toString()%>") ){    
            qtdAtivos = ativos.push("<%=arrExecute.get(1).toString()%>");            
        }


        data[cont]="<%=arrExecute.get(0).toString()%>";
        ativo[cont]="<%=arrExecute.get(1).toString()%>";        
        aproveitamento[cont]="<%=(arrExecute.get(2).toString().replaceAll(",", "."))%>";
        cont++;

    </struts_logic:iterate>

    var BarraApro =[];    
    var aDataset1 =[];


    for (var i=0;i < qtdAtivos;i++){    
        for( var t=cont; t >= qtdAtivos;t--){
            if( (ativos[i] == ativo[t]) ){    
                if (BarraApro[i] == [t]){                     
                    BarraApro[i] = Number(aproveitamento[t]);                   
                } else {
                    BarraApro[i] = BarraApro[i] +", "+ Number(aproveitamento[t]);   
                }                
            }

        } 

        aDataset1.push( {
          type: "bar",
          label: ativos[i],
          backgroundColor: cores[i],
          data: BarraApro[i].split(',').map(parseFloat),
          borderColor: "white",
          borderWidth: 2
        },)
        }

</script>               


<script>
    var chartData = {                    
        labels: aLabels,                    
        datasets: aDataset1
    };                

      Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'black';
    window.onload = function() {
                  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                  window.myMixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: "bar",
                    data: chartData,
                    options: {
                      responsive: false,
                      title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: "Horas Produtivas (h/dia)"                                                  
                      },

                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                        return value + 'h' ;
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        },
                      tooltips: {
                        enabled: false,
                        mode: "index",
                        intersect: true
                      },
                        animation: {
                            onComplete: function () {
                                var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
                                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                                ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                                this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset)
                                {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                                        for(var key in dataset._meta)
                                        {
                                            var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
                                            ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 5);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                          },
                      annotation: {
                        events: ["click"],
                        annotations: [
                          {
                            drawTime: "afterDatasetsDraw",
                            id: "facaline",
                            type: "line",
                            mode: "horizontal",
                            scaleID: "y-axis-0",
                            value: 7.2,
                            borderColor: "orange",
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            label: {
                              backgroundColor: "orange",
                              content: "Méta 7,2h/dia",
                              enabled: true,
                              position: "right",
                              xAdjust: 20,
                            }
                          }            

                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  });
                };
```

Comment: Provavelmente é um problema de "promise", experimente carregar o gráfico após o dado ser retornado. Para saber se está chegando o dado dentro do `window.onload = () => { ... }`, faça um `console.log(chartData)` dentro e veja o que retorna no console do seu navegador.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cmAacAt

Retornou isso amigo

Comment: Era pra retornar dados no datasets?

Comment: Eu mudei um pouco, na var BarraApro=[] eu passei [aprov]
e dei um console log no aDataset1

ele está passando os valores todos para um ativo só

da uma olhada eu grifei https://imgur.com/a/DccjSB8

Comment: E agora, resolveu o problema então?

Comment: Não kkkkkk consegui mudar um pouco, da uma olhado o codigo como ficou
https://imgur.com/a/8knKly0

e o grafico
https://imgur.com/a/mF6ZCV2

porem ele tem 6 Ativos, e só está puxando 2 agora, mas os dois que consegui puxar eles estão mostrando na data correta com os valores corretos, eu só não sei porque ele rodou o for só duas vezes uma pro ativo 74100 e uma para o 72797
era para rodar mais 4 vezes para mostrar os outros ativos também

Comment: provavelmente o problema agora está no seu for...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105791/discussion-between-rm08-and-ivan-ferrer).

Comment: help kk ainda não consegui resolver o problema

Comment: Você não consegue publicar um http://jsfiddle.net/ do que vc tem até agora, pra que alguém possa te ajudar, é preciso entender o problema frontend, já que é uma questão de front e não de  backend. [*]

Comment: [...] Sua pergunta ficaria mais objetiva se vc removesse conteúdo backend e colocasse o retorno da sua API como sua saída resolvida e a pergunta fosse a partir do frontend (que parece ser o problema em si, estou certo?) [..]

Comment: [..] Você pode usar `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` para pegar a saída JSON e copiar na pergunta.

Comment: Como está ficando o grafico: https://imgur.com/a/sWZpmwE
Como está no banco de dados... https://imgur.com/a/XaRpPbz
Segue o codigo javascript e também o select: https://jsfiddle.net/b642pv8n/1/

Comment: Vc precisa montar um fiddle funcional, vc colou tudo de qualquer jeito, vc já utilizou o fiddle alguma vez? No fiddle, a área de javascript não leva tag. Você colou código backend... a ideia não é chumbar tudo deste jeito...

Comment: Veja um exemplo funcional: https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/mg2zv3q9/

Comment: Desculpa Ivan eu não tinha usado jsfiddle antes, eu até entendi o modo de como usou o gráfico, meu problema ta em popular o gráfico com os dados que vem do banco de dados, meu laço de repetição deve estar errado então os dados não estão passando no local correto do gráfico